# How do I access the user UID in my firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a fantasy soccer web app based on a local league. So far, when a user is created using firebase auth, there is a respective node created in my firebase using the user uid as follows:

```
  $scope.signUp = function (){
   var username = $scope.user.email;
   var password = $scope.user.password;
   var teamname = $scope.user.teamname;
   var fullname = $scope.user.fullname;

   var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');

   if(username && password){
     var auth = $firebaseAuth();
         auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, 
       password).then(function(user){
             console.log("User Successfully Created");
            let usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
             //child is created under users node with a user's user id as 
        child name
            usersRef.child(user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                userName: username,
                teamname: teamname,
                fullname: fullname,
                total: 0,
                week:0
              });

             $location.path('/home');
         }).catch(function(error){
            $scope.errMsg = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
         });
          }
          };
```

That part works fine. In the database, the JSON tree looks something like this:

```
users:{
         user UID: {
                    email:
                    teamname:
                    fullname:
                    week:
                  }
       }
```

I have a service I use for all my views :

```
.service('CommonProp',['$location','$firebaseAuth', function($location,$firebaseAuth){
    var user = "";
    var auth = $firebaseAuth();

  return {
      getUser:function(){
          if(user == ""){
         user = localStorage.getItem("userEmail"); 
          }
          return user;
      },
      setUser: function(value){
        localStorage.setItem("userEmail", value);  
         user = value; 
      },
      logoutUser: function(){
         auth.$signOut();
         console.log("Logged Out Successfully");
         user = "";
         localStorage.removeItem("userEmail");
         $location.path('/home');
      }
      };
      }]);
```

PROBLEM

My problem is that when I go to my 'select player' view, I do not know how to access the user UID so that I can set each user's selection for each week.This is what I tried to do :`

```
$scope.saveTeam = function(user){
   $scope.history = [];
   var uid = user.uid;
   var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("users/" + auth.uid + "/week"); 
   ref2.set($scope.history);
};
```

Is there a way that I can access each user's respective "week" child node under their respective user uid?

Comment: You'll want to monitor `auth.$onAuthStateChanged` for that. See https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#retrieving-authentication-state

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen using auth.$onAuthStateChanged how exactly would the firebase database in my code, "ref2" , get the respective user's uid? Sorry the github link does not make this clear

Comment: You'd get it from `firebaseUser.uid`.